# How to extract zip code from reverse geocoding in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, tiger, reverse-geocoding, zip-codes

I have a bunch of lat/lng coordinates that I can reverse geocode, after having installed PostGIS and the relevant Tiger files.

I throw in a query like this:

```
select reverse_geocode(ST_Point(lng, lat))
from plus_viewable
limit 5
```

And so far, get results like the following:

```
({0101000020AD10000041F2CEA10C2055C08AE76C01A1F54040},"{""(1343,,Franklin,Dr,,,Marietta,GA,30067,)""}","{""Cobb Pkwy S""}")
```

I just need to be able to extract the zip code.

How would I be able to do that?

Answer (score -1):

You pull in the [ZCTA](https://www.census.gov/geo/reference/zctas.html), and then you do a [point-in-polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) search on it with something like `ST_Intersects`.

These isn't exact, but because the USPS doesn't release a dataset it's as good as you can get. It's good enough for the Census for what it's worth.